# Checkbox Deleting - If statement inside For loop deletes wrong entries

Tags: php, sql, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I have a page which displays my database information.  Through each loop, there is a checkbox printed that is to delete the associated entry if checked and submitted.  The checkbox names are 'delete[]' and there is the hidden value which contains the row id is named 'id[]'.

This is the relevant part of my form:

```
<tr><td valign='top'>
<label class='amarillo med' style='color:#C00;'>Delete Section </label>
<input type='checkbox' name='delete[]' />
<input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='" . $row['about_id'] . "' />
</td></tr>
```

This is my php and query

```
$deleteCount = count($_POST['delete']);
for ($x = 0; $x < $deleteCount; $x++) {
if(isset($_POST['delete'][$x])) {
   $sql = 'DELETE FROM about WHERE about_id = \''.$_POST['id'][$x].'\'';
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
}
```

This is what happens.

If three rows are returned and I want to delete only the third, I check the third box and click submit.  This deletes the first row that was returned.  Again, if three rows are returned and I want to delete the first and third, I submit and the first two rows are deleted.

What it looks like is happening is for every checkbox that is checked, that many rows are deleted starting with the first.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Include your form, too. Everything that is applicable.

Comment: the problem is from what `id[]` is returning .. include how you are generating value for `id`

Comment: I have updated to include the relevant parts of my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and much easier way is to use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="<?=$row['about_id']?>"/>
```

and then

```
foreach($_REQUEST['delete'] as $delID)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: As a basic security measure, use $_POST not $_GET or $_REQUEST when modifying data; it makes CSRF attacks harder.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery.

Comment: I don't recomend to interpret any advices so literally. Using $_GET or $_POST or even $_REQUEST must be based on application's requirments. One ought to solve CSRF problem in other way. And that was just an example.

Comment: The HTTP specification recommends that GET not be used to modify data (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), so it's good practice in addition to making any CSRF vulnerabilities harder to exploit.  You're right that it isn't sufficient, but it dramatically increases the difficulty of exploitation.

Comment: I was able to use this with $_POST versus the $_REQUEST and it seems to work like a charm.  Thank you very much!  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
<tr><td valign='top'>
<label class='amarillo med' style='color:#C00;'>Delete Section </label>
<input type='checkbox' name='delete[$row['id']]' />
<input type='hidden' name='id[$row['id']]' value='" . $row['about_id'] . "' />
</td></tr>
```

where $row['id'] is the id of the row

Comment: If I did this, how would I then structure my loop?